# Unity C# clear images on button click

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a script in Unity that will display an image on a UI button click and then when another UI button is pressed those images will go away and the new images associated with the button that was just pressed will appear. So if I push button A image A will appear and then if I push button B image A will go away and image B will appear.  This is what I have so far. I was using this code to display my image when a button is click which works:

```
public Image myImage;

void Start ()
{
    myImage.enabled = false;                //image hidden at scene start
}

public void buttonClick()                   //when user clicks button
{   
    myImage.enabled = true;                 //image appears
}
```

Obviously nothing in there tells the image to go away so I tried to set whether or not the button was clicked with something like this:

```
void Start ()
{
    myImage.enabled = false;                //image hidden at scene start
}

public void buttonClick()                   //when user clicks button
{   
    bool checkClick = true;                 

    if (checkClick = true)                  //if button clicked
    {
        myImage.enabled = true;             //display image
    }
    else if (checkClick = false)            //if button not clicked
    {
        myImage.enabled = false;            //image hidden
    }
}
```

}

Which doesn't work at all. I think I need the void Update() in there so it is checking to see what state the button is in, but I haven't gotten that to work either. I'm probably missing something simple, coding isn't really my thing. I would greatly appreciate suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`if (checkClick = true)` should be  `if (checkClick == true)` and so on. As `=` is the assignment operator while `==` is the comparison operator.

Fix that then debug and make sure your logic/ design is working as expected.

Comment: So changing the = to == made the code work just like the first block I had.  In the debugger it never gets to the else if statement though.

Comment: You said you have two buttons, why you are using only one even handler `ButtonClick()`? Is not it suppose to be somthing like: `ButtonOneClick() { enable Image A and disable Image B}` then on `ButtonTwoClick() { disable Image A and enable Image B}`?

Comment: I have 20 buttons, I was just using two for the explanation.

Comment: The best design then Amanda is to **load** the desired image for each `ButtonClick()`. 20 buttons = 20 `ButtonClick()`s. On each ButtonClick, **load** the desired image, and display it. One ImageControl for all ButtonClicks. You could as well load all the images first, and at once, into some container, then on each ButtonClick, choose the desired index and take its value (image) and display it.

Comment: That works too...but then when I click the buttons the new images pop up and the previous images are still there.

Comment: @Amanda, If you are using **only one ImageControl** on your form, there is no way you will see two images. Unless you combine programmatic-ally (AND) two images and then display their result (Which is a single image).

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by ImageControl. Is that just a empty game object?

Comment: @Amanda ImageControl is the ImageBox. The "tool" you drag and drop on your form. Like when you grab a button and you put in on the form. In WPF it is called ImageControl. In WinForms it is called ImageBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
public void buttonClick()                   //when user clicks button
{   
    bool checkClick = true;  

    myImage.enabled = checkClick;
}
```

But in your case `checkClick` will always be true. You should declare it as class property and change value when click (by `checkClick != checkClick`).

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attach this script to any object and assign all (20) images to in images from inspector.
/// </summary>
public class ImageContainor : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The List of images to choose from.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Image> images = new List<Image>(20);

}

/// <summary>
/// Attach this script to all the buttons.
/// </summary>
public class ButtonClickHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The image containor reference, assign the object on which you have ImageContainor script from inspector.
    /// </summary>
    public ImageContainor imageContainor;


    /// <summary>
    /// Register this method as OnClick() Handler from inspector.
    /// Set index parameter accordingly to enable/disable desired image with this button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index.</param>
    public void ButtonClick(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageContainor.images.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
            {
                imageContainor.images[i].enabled == true;
            }
            else
            {
                imageContainor.images[i].enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This will fail as `imageContainor` is not initialized.

Comment: If you look closely, `ImageContainor` is `MonoBehaviour` and will be assigned from inspector.